# Low Search - Why does a range value evaluate to a blank string instead of a literal 0?

Tags: low-search

There seems to be a problem with having a zero(0) value in a select dropdown.

I am using select dropdown to do some minimum-maximum ranges on a field.

```
<select name="range-from:foo">
<option value="">Min Foo</option>
<option {if "0" IN ({low_search_range-from:foo})}selected="selected"{/if} value="0">0</option>
....
</select>
<select name="range-to:foo" id="property_number_of_bedrooms_to">
<option value="">Max Foo</option>
<option {if "0" IN ({low_search_range-to:foo})}selected="selected"{/if} value="0">0</option>
....
</select>
```

I tried choosing the option with value="0" and then submit. When I get back on the page, the option with the value="" is selected.

I tried outputting {low_search_range-from:foo} and {low_search_range-to:foo} and they both output a blank string.

It seems that low search probably type casted this to a string which returned a blank string.

How to solve this? I want to get 0 as my value literally when the option value is 0.

Comment: See https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/why_does_a_range_value_evaluate_to_a_blank_string_instead_of_a_literal_0#reply_11776243 -- Upgrade to latest version first, then see if problem persists.

Comment: Ok. Upgrading to the latest version solved it.

Comment: @arvinsim Can you post your comment as an answer for resolving your issue?

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl Low has posted it as the official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an official answer. The question was related to Low Search version 2.1.2. Upgrading to the latest version (currently 2.3.0) solved this issue.